# How to detect if a key is held?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a dodging game, where objects fall from the top of the window that the player must dodge or collect, depending on whether it is a triangle or a circle. Right now I am doing the layout, and making the moveable icon, which is a smiley face emoji. I am using a `keyListener` to move the icon(using WASD controls). Right now when you want to move the image with the `keyPressed` method you have to press and release the keys, rather than holding them.
How can I make the icon move just by holding the keys, instead of pressing and releasing the keys rapidly?

Info:  The background is a `JLabel` which the player chooses at the beginning through a `JOptionPane`. All of the background images are in the source folder, and are all 500*300 pixel jpg's. My application is run on a Mac OS X, if that helps at all.

Thanks, and here's my Program:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Dodge extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1l;
    String[] backDrops = {"space", "sky", "snow", "rain", "beach", "grass"};
    ImageIcon backDrop;
    String[] options = {"Easy", "Medium", "Difficult"};
    String result;
    String bd;
    int x; 
    int y;
    int difficulty;
    int wait = difficulty * 500;
    Graphics g;

    public Dodge() {
        getPreferences();
        layoutGame();
        setTitle("Dodge The Objects!");
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void getPreferences() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Welcome to Dodge. The rules are simple:"
                + "\n\t\t\t\t1. Choose a level"
                + "\n\t\t\t\t2. Choose a back drop"
                + "\n\t\t\t\t3. Use the arrow keys to move"
                + "\n\t\t\t\t4. Avoid triangles and collect the circles");

          JOptionPane difficultyChoice = new JOptionPane("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tChoose your difficulty:",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
                null, options, options[1]);
          JDialog difficultyWindow = difficultyChoice.createDialog(null, "1. Difficulty");
          difficultyWindow.setVisible(true);
          result = (String) difficultyChoice.getValue();
          if(difficultyChoice.equals("Easy")) {
              difficulty = 3;
          } else if(difficultyChoice.equals("Medium")) {
              difficulty = 2;
          } else if(difficultyChoice.equals("Difficult")) {
              difficulty = 1;
          }

          JOptionPane backDropOption = new JOptionPane("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tChoose your back drop:",
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
                    null, backDrops, backDrops[0]);
          JDialog backDropWindow = backDropOption.createDialog(null, "2. Back Drop");
          backDropWindow.setVisible(true);
          bd = (String) backDropOption.getValue();
          backDrop = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(bd + ".png"));
    }

    private void layoutGame() {
        JLabel title = new JLabel("Dodge The Enemies!");
        Font titleFont = new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, 32);
        title.setFont(titleFont);
        title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        title.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        title.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        title.setOpaque(true);
        add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JLabel background = new JLabel();
        background.setIcon(backDrop);
        add(background, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        x=230;
        y=120;
        JLabel you = new JLabel();
        you.setBounds(x, y, 50, 50);
        you.setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("happy.png")));
        background.add(you, JLabel.CENTER);

        JTextPane direction = new JTextPane();
        direction.setText("Direction");
        add(direction, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        direction.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyChar() == 'w') {
                    y-=2;
                } else if (e.getKeyChar() == 's') {
                    y+=2;
                } else if (e.getKeyChar() == 'a') {
                    x-=2;
                } else if (e.getKeyChar() == 'd') {
                    x+=2;
                }
                you.setBounds(x, y, 50, 50);
                direction.setText("   \t   \t   \t   ");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            String className = UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName();
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(className);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Dodge();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially with falling objects, you are going to need to look into something called a "game loop".

What a "game loop" allows you to do, basically, is have actions that are repeated over and over; but unlike a normal loop, it's properly timed to achieve what we mostly know as "FPS" or "Frames per Second" which basically measures how quickly your game loops every second.

Here's a very good resource on game loops:
http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24220.0

In theory, when you have your game loop, what you will do is set a boolean to true when you press a button like 'w', 'a', 's', or 'd' and in your loop  have an if-statement that checks whether one of those booleans are true and then moves your `JLabel` like before.

ex.

```
/* ... */

    direction.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyChar() == 'w') {
                wIsPressed = true;
            }
            // a, s, d
            // ...
        });

/* ... */

    // In game loop
    if (wIsPressed) {
        y -= 2;
    }
    // a, s, d
    // ...

    you.setBounds(x, y, 50, 50);

/* ... */
```

You will also need to have a listener for when a key is released, not just pressed to set those boolean to false.

The KeyAdapter class has a `keyReleased` method to override alongside the `keyPressed`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyAdapter.html