# Swing KeyListener doesn't work when pressing Shift X Z and directions at the same time

Tags: java, keyboard, swing

My code:

```
addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() >= KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && event.getKeyCode() <= KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
            direction.set(event.getKeyCode() - KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, true);
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Z) direction.set(4, true);
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)          System.out.println(event.getKeyCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() >= KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && event.getKeyCode() <= KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            speed = event.isShiftDown() ? 1 : fastSpeed;
            direction.set(event.getKeyCode() - KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, false);
        }
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Z) direction.set(4, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    }
});
```

I start my application and press `Shift`, `Z`, and `X` at the same time, at this moment everything was fine (Successfully see command line output).
But when I press UP or DOWN, swing isn't invoking my listener (no command line output).

I've repeated many times and it's all the same.

Is there any work-arounds?

Comment: Do you mean that the arrow keys don't work when Shift+Z+X are already pressed? This may be a hardware limitation of your keyboard.

Comment: Oh.... so is there an alternative workaround?

Comment: You can usually combo any/all modifier keys (shift, control, alt) in addition to at least one other key, so try seeing if this works if you move Z & X to other keys.

Comment: I've tried <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> and only <kbd>Z</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> cause this issue

Comment: @ice1000 if you look at your keyboard you see that A, S, D, Z, X, Shift, Ctrl, Alt, Super are all located in a single corner of the keyboard. It is very likely that there's a physical limitation

Comment: @ice1000 a workaround? it depends on what you are trying to achieve. You can't defeat hardware limitations by software means. There may be keyboards with other internal layouts, allowing more simultaneous keypresses. Probably more expensive. However, unless your software runs on a single machine, you really shouldn't rely on such capabilities.

Comment: Otherwise, the workaround is trivial. Use other key combination. Probably instead of several keys pressed at once you might watch for a key sequence. IDDQD anyone?

Comment: I had the same exact problem. I just decided to use the keys not the arrows. I used it in [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/144566/how-can-i-make-diagonal-movement)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your recapitulation this might be an [key rollover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)) problem.

The term *key rollover* describes a tradeoff in keyboard design complexity for reduced production cost. Many standard keyboards have issues detecting more than three keys being pressed simultaneously.

As you are using Swing, that means you are using java. So in order to find out if it is a software or a hardware limitation you could try the following things:

- write a simple Swing application that only outputs the pressed keys and see if the input combo works
- write an even simpler AWT application, instead of using Swing, to really only output key-input to make some tests
- write a simple [JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm) application, instead of either AWT or Swing. JavaFX is the recommended replacement for Swing and if it is a software problem JavaFX is likely to have it fixed
- have a look at [LWJGL](https://www.lwjgl.org/) and it's bindings to the [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) library which provides an alternative way to get keyboard-inputs (this would allow you to find out if the Java standard libraries are the baddies...)